# How to initialize Google's maps inside jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, knockout.js

I'm developing a web application. I need compatibility with IE8 and above. I'm using knockout.js for MVVM pattern.

```html
<!-- Dialog Customer Geolocalization -->
<div id="geolocalization-customer-dialog" class="dialog" data-bind="template: { name: 'geolocalization-template', data: BasicViewModel.CustomerViewModel }"></div>

<!-- Dialog supplier Geolocalization -->
<div id="geolocalization-supplier-dialog" class="dialog" data-bind="template: { name: 'geolocalization-template', data: BasicViewModel.SupplierViewModel }"></div>

<!-- Geolocalization template -->
<script type="text/html" id="geolocalization-template">
    <div id="mapsAddress">
        <table>
            <tr class="ucTitle">
                <td>Zip Code</td>
                <td>District</td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Street</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="txZipCode" type="text" data-bind="value: ZipCode"/></td>
                <td><input id="txProvince" type="text" data-bind="value: Province"/></td>
                <td><input id="txCity" type="text" data-bind="value: City"/></td>
                <td><input id="txStreet" type="text" data-bind="value: Street"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="maps" class="maps"></div>
</script>
```

I initialize the maps with the JavaScript code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        initMap();
        ko.applyBindings(BasicViewModel);
    } catch (ex) {
        WriteToConsole("Error code:" + ex.ErrorNumber + " Error message:" + ex.message);
    }
}

function initMap()
    try {
        map = new google.maps.Map($("#geolocalization-customer-dialog div#maps")[0], {
            center: { 
                lat: -34.397, 
                lng: 150.644 
            },
            zoom: 8
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        WriteToConsole("Error on initializing Google Maps:" + ex.ErrorNumber + " Error message:" + ex.message);
    }
}
```

I obtain this error:

> "Impossible retrieve the property 'offsetWidth' of null reference"

Note that the div with id `geolocalization-customer-dialog` and `geolocalization-supplier-dialog` are used with jQuery dialog.

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with this code:

```
$("#geolocalization-customer-dialog").dialog(
        {
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            create: initMap(), // <-- Here must be initializated the maps
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "OK"
                },
                {
                    text: "Geolocalize"
                }
            ]
        });
```

The map must be initializated on creation of dialog. I don't know why, I think that if the `<div>` element have the property display:none it not works.